# Cannot move a file to another folder. Error returns on a wrong path

Tags: c#, path, windows-services

Here's my code in moving excel file to be specific..

```
       if (Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath, "*.xls").Length != 0)
            {
                //Move files to history folder
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath); //value -- D://FS//
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    var fName = Path.GetFileName(s); //12232015.xls
                    var sourcePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fName);
                    var destFile = Path.Combine(historyPath, fName); // -- D://FS//History
                    File.Move(fName, destFile);
                }
            }
```

But it gets an error of 
 `Could not find file 'D:\Project\ProjectService\bin\Debug\12232015.xls'.`

Why it finds under my project not on the specific folder i set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only using the name of the file:

```
var fName = Path.GetFileName(s); //12232015.xls
//...
File.Move(fName, destFile);
```

Without a complete path, the system will look in the current working directory.  Which is the directory where the application is executing.

You should use the entire path for the source file:

```
File.Move(sourcePath, destFile);
```

Explicitly specifying the full path is *almost always* the best approach.  Relative paths are notoriously difficult to manage.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is an Logical error. Change

```
File.Move(fName, destFile);
```

to

```
File.Move(sourcePath, destFile);
```

as `fName` only contains file name and not fullpath. The file is checked in working directory.